SpreadSheetLigth Error after update package nuget visual studio
actualicé todos los paquetes NuGet de mi proyecto windows form c# visual studio 2022, y spreedsheetligth tenia la version reciente, por lo que no actualizó.
me salian los siguientes errores cuando trataba de exportar datos a excel.
cuando estaba x64
Asistente para la depuración administrada 'FatalExecutionEngineError'
Mensaje = Asistente para la depuración administrada 'FatalExecutionEngineError': "El runtime detectó un error irrecuperable. La dirección del error fue 0x7338cc80, en el subproceso 0x63cc. El código de error es 0xc0000005. Es posible que este error sea un error de CLR o de partes no seguras y no verificables de código de usuario. Entre los orígenes más habituales de este error se encuentran los errores de cálculo de referencias para la interoperabilidad COM o PInvoke, que pueden dañar la pila."
y el otro error cuando lo probaba en x86, creanme pasé horas buscando la solución.
System.AccessViolationException: 'Intento de leer o escribir en la memoria protegida. A menudo, esto indica que hay otra memoria dañada.'
entonces resulta, encontré en este foro : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451431/managed-debugging-assistant-fatalexecutionengineerror
leyendo detenidamente cada respuesta, busqué el paquete OpenXml y comparé con el de otro proyecto y si se había actualizado, en la versión 3.0 hacia adelante produce errores, en la versiones 2.20 hacia atrás parece funcionar todo bien.
